# scalafix autofix plugin error "error: repeated argument not allowed here" when varargs are present in the codebase

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, sbt-plugin, scalafix

I'm using varargs like below in my code base.

```
 def acceptVarargs[S](s: S*): Unit = {}
 def toVarArgs[T](s: Seq[T]) = acceptVarargs(s: _*)
```

I'm using [autofix](https://github.com/scalatest/autofix/tree/master/3.0.x) plugin in my sbt [project](https://github.com/rajcspsg/varargs-scalafix-error/blob/master/project/plugins.sbt#L1).

I'm following the steps [here](https://github.com/scalatest/autofix/tree/master/3.0.x) to run the scalafix command.

When I run the command `sbt> scalafixAll dependency:RenameDeprecatedPackage@org.scalatest:autofix:3.0.8-1` I get below Error.

> [error] /Users/rajkumar.natarajan/Documents/Coding/misc/varargs-scalafix-error/src/main/scala/Utils.scala:3: error: repeated argument not allowed here
> [error]   def toVarArgs[T](s: Seq[T]) = acceptVarargs(s: _*)
> [error]                                               ^
> [error]         at scala.meta.internal.parsers.Reporter.syntaxError(Reporter.scala:16)
> [error]         at scala.meta.internal.parsers.Reporter.syntaxError$(Reporter.scala:16)
> [error]         at scala.meta.internal.parsers.Reporter$$anon$1.syntaxError(Reporter.scala:22)
> [error]         at scala.meta.internal.parsers.Reporter.syntaxError(Reporter.scala:17)
> [error]         at scala.meta.internal.parsers.Reporter.syntaxError$(Reporter.scala:17)

The complete error stack trace is [here](https://gist.github.com/rajcspsg/fb7d12fbe14ed2381f3a5691c4f33a0f)

What is wrong in my codebase with varargs? How can I fix this error?

The project in github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/varargs-scalafix-error)

Other details -

sbt version - 1.5.2
scala version - 2.12.10
java version - 11.0.10-zulu

Comment: According to the compiler error, the actual code is `def toVarArgs[T](s: Seq[T]) = s: _*`, not `def toVarArgs[T](s: Seq[T]) = acceptVarargs(s: _*)`. Is it possible that you didn't save changes to the file before running `scalafixAll`?

Comment: @MichałPawlicki - It happens for both. Anyhow I fixed the error in question.